# How to add a Header for a "sencha" "dataview"

Tags: mobile, salesforce1-app, salesforce-sencha

I am displaying a set of records from store using dataview. I want to show it as 5 columns and I have achieved it. What I need to now is, a header for it. A header row that would tell what each column has inside. My code is as below

```
{ 
//List for displaying the Investors.
    xtype: "dataview",
    store: "Investors",
    itemId : "InvestorsList",

    indexBar: false,
    grouped: false,
    disableSelection: false,
    loadingText: "Loading Investors...",
    emptyText: '<div class="leads-list-empty-text">No Investors found.</div>',
    itemCls : "dataview-item",
    itemTpl:[
        '<table border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;"><tr>',
        '<td style="width:20%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Account__c}</td>',
        '<td style="width:20%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Primary_Contact_Name__c}</td>',
        '<td style="width:20%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;"><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Accepted&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-acceptedClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Pending&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-pendingClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Final Bidder&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-finalClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Dropped&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-droppedClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Rejected&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-rejectedClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl></td>',
        '<td style="width:15%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Contact_Phone__c}</td>',
        '<td style="width:25%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Primary_Contact_Email__c}</td>',
        '</tr></table>'
    ],
}
```

I tried adding "html", adding toolbar but it doesn't help. I think you can understand that data would display like table, how to add one row(header) to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add header by defining table a toolbar in sencha, `xtype: 'toolbar'`

```
    // Your code
    config: {
             items: [
             { 
                //List for displaying the Investors.
                xtype: "dataview",
                store: "Investors",
                itemId : "InvestorsList",

                indexBar: false,
                grouped: false,
                disableSelection: false,
                loadingText: "Loading Investors...",
                emptyText: '<div class="leads-list-empty-text">No Investors found.</div>',
                 itemCls : "dataview-item",
                 itemTpl:[
                    '<table border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;"><tr>',
                    '<td style="width:20%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Account__c}</td>',
                    '<td style="width:20%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Primary_Contact_Name__c}</td>',
                    '<td style="width:20%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;"><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Accepted&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-acceptedClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Pending&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-pendingClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Final Bidder&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-finalClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Dropped&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-droppedClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl><tpl if="Status__c == &quot;Rejected&quot;"><div class="list-item-line-rejectedClass">{Status__c}</div></tpl></td>',
                    '<td style="width:15%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Contact_Phone__c}</td>',
                    '<td style="width:25%; text-align: center; line-height: 3;  font-size: 16px;">{Primary_Contact_Email__c}</td>',
                    '</tr></table>'
                   ]
               },
               {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'MyHEader'
               }
            ]
         }
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that, I need 5 words as the header and It should come exactly above the table columns.

Answer (score 0):

At present I solved this issue by docking a panel in the top. I have defined a table in the panel as "html" that would display 5 words, each above every column. It is as below:

```
items: [
{
    xtype: "toolbar",
    //some code
},
{
    docked: 'top',
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 40,
    html: '<table border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width:100%;margin-top:0px;"><tr><td></td></tr></table>'
},
{
    //My dataview
}
```

It is good to view NOW but have to use it and find how it is performing.